# WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER but only for script from file, not console

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I want retreive info from mail certificate. I use this code:

```
konektilo = socket.socket()
konektilo.connect(("9…9", 25))
konektilo.send(b"STARTTLS\n")
konektilo.recv(1024)
ssl_konektilo = ssl.wrap_socket(konektilo)
certigilo_der = ssl_konektilo.getpeercert(True)
konektilo.close()
```

This works fine and I can receive a certificate when run this code from python console:

```
# python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket, ssl
>>> from OpenSSL import crypto
>>> konektilo = socket.socket()
>>> konektilo.connect(("9…9", 25))
>>> konektilo.send(b"STARTTLS\n")
9
>>> konektilo.recv(1024)
b"220 … ESMTP …\r\n220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n"
>>> ssl_konektilo = ssl.wrap_socket(konektilo)
>>> certigilo_der = ssl_konektilo.getpeercert(True)
>>> konektilo.close()
>>> certigilo = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, certigilo_der)
>>> certigilo
<OpenSSL.crypto.X509 object at 0x7fcd5b7ecda0>
```

But when I put this into file — I got an error:

```
# cat /tmp/a.py
import socket, ssl
from OpenSSL import crypto
konektilo = socket.socket()
konektilo.connect(("9…9", 25))
konektilo.send(b"STARTTLS\n")
konektilo.recv(1024)
ssl_konektilo = ssl.wrap_socket(konektilo)
certigilo_der = ssl_konektilo.getpeercert(True)
konektilo.close()
certigilo = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, certigilo_der)
print(certigilo)
# python3 /tmp/a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 7, in <module>
    ssl_konektilo = ssl.wrap_socket(konektilo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1158, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)
```